# $match Dates in mongodb using aggregation, mongoose model schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i am trying to fetch some data from my DB that match with today Date.

this is my data model.

```
new Schema({
    description: { type: String },
    valid: { type: Date },
    discount: { type: Number },
})
```

I am trying this...

```
   {
                                    $lookup: {
                                        from: "offers",
                                        let: { "idOffer": "$offer" },
                                        as: "offers",
                                        pipeline: [
                                            {
                                                $match: {
                                                    $expr: {
                                                        $and: [
                                                            { $eq: ['$_id', '$$idOffer'] },
                                                            { $gte: [new Date('$valid'), new Date()] }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
```

What i pretend is to fetch the offers that is still valid today, but it is not working... what am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[new Date('$valid')` - since `valid` is defined as _Date_ type, you should be able to use without the `new Date()`.

Comment: huh, exactly it is working without "new Date" Thanks!, the thing is that im used to use new date to build the Date in the frontend thats why i used it like this.